# Application to draw "Rich Pictures"

Tags: macos, applications, drawing

Any software to draw ["Rich Pictures"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_picture) diagrams of Information Systems Analysis?
I searched for a stencil for OmniGraffle but didn't find anything.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on what you mean by "Rich Pictures" or give an example?

Comment: @robmathers I updated my post to include a link to Wikipedia

Comment: From that description it sounds like exactly the sort of drawing that OmniGraffle is great at, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: I would edit in more about what about rich pictures up want. There are myriad drawing apps, mind mapping apps, outline apps available but it's not clear how omnigraffle is failing your use case.